# RxAndroidBle scanBleDevices(UUID...) not firing

Tags: rx-android, rxandroidble

I am having trouble using the scanBleDevices method when passing it a (valid) UUID - the subscribe will never fire.  Currently I have a working prototype using the usual android methods of scanning, connecting, read/write, but I want to update my syntax of RxAndroidBle to make things more safe and more easy to read.

Here is my RxAndroidBle implementation - **not working / subscribe never fires:**

[image]

You may be thinking that my UUID is wrong, but here is some alternative implementation that I did using a very stateful previous version -  **same uuid, this works:**

[image]

mLeScanCallback will be fired.

I am using RxAndroidBle version 1.2.2 & my phone is a Nexus 6P android version 6.0.1

Some additional info:
If I use scanBleDevices(), no parameters, I can find my desired rxBleScanResult by checking something in the manufacture data, which I will be doing anyway.  But I would like to filter on the UUID too to be safe.  When I had found my desired package bytes[] I tried to extract my UUID using the (deprecated)
`new UUIDUtil().extractUUIDs(rxBleScanResult.getScanRecord())`, but this returned an empty list.  And just to nail things down a little more, when I use the old fashioned mLeScanCallback, the above extractUUIDS is also resulting in an empty list.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a bug in the `RxAndroidBle` library. 
As one could see in the `UUIDUtil` (https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/commit/ee59e0ab9ae3c483f5c4f35c7729e9fc2068ee21#diff-c7944d4c01c56adf4e6c67c7f7f737e8) — which is responsible for extracting service UUIDs from bluetooth advertisement — it was lacking of 32-bit UUIDs. The fix is added in a just released version `1.2.3`.

Comment: This works!  Thanks s_noopy!  I was wondering your opinion on the health of RxAndroidBle.  They are very fast to repair things - however maybe it is not production ready?  I love this library.  I think I will go ahead with it anyway.

Comment: So actually under the hood, filtering based on the ScanPackage byte array is the same as filtering on the scanBleDevices(UUID...) method?  Oh well!

Comment: This library is used on production already in several different projects and if your peripheral does not change services and does not use encrypted characteristics - it's ready to use - the above issues are next to tackle . I don't get the ScanPackage part.